# Creating a decorator / cache for checking global variable

Tags: python, global-variables, decorator, nameerror

I've quite a few functions that uses some global variables to hold an object to be reused throughout the library, e.g.:

```
from some.other.lib import Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4, Object5

def function1(input):
    global _object1
    try:
        _object1
    except NameError:
        _object1 = Object1
    return _object1.func1(input)


def function2(input):
    global _object2
    try:
        _object2
    except NameError:
        _object2 = Object2
    # Use function1 to do something to the input
    return _object2.func2(function1(input))


def function3(input):
    global _object3
    try:
        _object3
    except NameError:
        _object3 = Object3
    # Use function1 to do something to the input.
    return _object3.func3(function1(input))


def function4(input):
    global _object4
    try:
        _object4
    except NameError:
        _object4 = Object4
    return _object4.func4(input)


def function5(input):
    global _object5
    try:
        _object5
    except NameError:
        _object5 = Object5
    # Use function4 to do something to the input.
    return _object5.func5(function4(input))
```

Is there a way to write a decorator such that the code to check the global variable doesn't need to be manually hardcoded for each of the `function*`?

E.g. something like:

```
def exist_decorator(_object, _class):
    try:
        _object
    except NameError:
        _object = _class
    return _object
```

So the actual class implementation for `function4()` will look like:

```
def function4(input):
    global _object4
    exist_decorator(_object4, Object4)
    return _object4.func4(input)
```

**Is something like this syntactically possible in Python with decorators?** If not, how else can I create a decorator/cache for checking global variable?

Comment: Decorators go on functions, not on statements.

Comment: Am I right if I assume that you are just abusing global variables to keep come kind of cache which is used only within a specific function?  Or are you intending to use the `_object1` also outside the scope of `function1()`?

Comment: Yes, I'm abusing it for caching a model (more specifically: https://github.com/alvations/earthy/blob/master/earthy/nltk_wrappers/__init__.py#L27) But I think there must be a better way to do this, but I'm not sure how to decouple the model make it stay in some cache and when a user wants to access the model.

Comment: Possibly, caching some sort of global variable and passing it `lru_cache`?

Comment: And `_object1` should be accessible outside the scope of `function1()`

Answer (score 4):

I guess you just want to cache some values.  For this the straight forward approach in decent Python without abusing any hidden feature is this:

```
cache = {}

def function1(input):
    try:
        object1 = cache['object1']
    except KeyError:
        object1 = cache['object1'] = Object1
    return object1.func1(input)
```

And similar for the other functions.

You can also avoid using the still-global variable `cache` by storing everything within your function object:

```
def function1(input):
    try:
        object1 = function1.object1
    except AttributeError:
        object1 = function1.object1 = Object1
    return object1.func1(input)
```

This is possible because functions are arbitrary objects to which you can add attributes.  But some might call this an abuse and unclean code.  As always in such cases, discuss this with your team first and maybe add it to the list of used techniques for this team or project before using it.

I prefer using the hidden feature of mutable arguments:

```
def function(input, object1Cache=[None]):
    if object1Cache[0] is None:
        object1Cache[0] = Object1
    return object1Cache[0].func1(input)
```

This works in Python because a list as a default value for a function parameter is still mutable and will keep its value.

And again, this might be considered unclean and an abuse, so discuss this with your team before using it and document in your project notes that this technique is used.

Comment: Would using something like https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/08/12/a-tip-for-the-impatient-simple-caching-with-python-pickle-and-decorators/ help?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of libraries (or just code snippets) for caching a value.  Caching it in a pickle file, however, means to cache it beyond the runtime of the process.  The next time you start this process the pickle file might still be around.  You never mentioned you wanted this feature, and none of my versions for caching does this, so I mention this implication.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use cached factory functions, and provide them as default args to the functions that depend on them. This eliminates global variables and adheres to the open / closed principle.

## my_objects.py

```
from functools import cache


class Object1:
    def __init__(self, a='foo', b='bar'):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


@cache
def get_object1():
    return Object1()
```

## my_function.py

```
from my_app.my_objects import get_object1


def function1(dependency_factory=get_object1):
    depends_on = dependency_factory()
    print(depends_on.a, depends_on.b)
```

An even cleaner approach is to create a decorator function to pass the instantiated dependencies, i.e. dependency injection.

## depends_on.py

```
def depends_on(**factories):
    def outer(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for name, factory in factories.items():
                kwargs[name] = factory()  # instantiate object by calling factory function or static method
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return outer
```

## my_db.py

```
from functools import cache


class DB:
    def save(self, x):
        if x == 'oops':
            raise ValueError(f'DB tried to save invalid value: {x}')
        print(f'{x} saved to db')


@cache
def get_db():
    return DB()
```

## my_logger.py

```
from functools import cache


class Logger:
    def info(self, x):
        print(f'INFO: {x}')


@cache
def get_logger():
    return Logger()
```

## save_and_log.py

```
from my_app.depends_on import depends_on
from my_app.my_db import get_db
from my_app.my_logger import get_logger


@depends_on(db=get_db, logger=get_logger)
def save_and_log(thing_to_save, db=None, logger=None):
    try:
        db.save(thing_to_save)
    except ValueError as e:
        logger.info(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_and_log('some persistent data')
    # outputs "some persistent data saved to db"
    save_and_log('oops')
    # outputs "INFO: DB tried to save invalid value: oops"
```