# Would the global variable inside a submodule be reloaded each time I call a function?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, global-variables, pickle

I have my library structured as such:

```
/topmost
   /__init__.py
   /submodule
       /__init__.py
```

With the `submodule.__init__.py`, there are several functions that makes use of global variables to communicate with each other:

```
import pickle

def function1(input):
    global _object1
    try:
        _object1
    except NameError:
        _object1 = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl', 'rb'))
    return _object1.func1(input)

def function2(input):
    global _object2
    try:
        _object2
    except NameError:
        _object2 = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl', 'rb'))
    # Use function1 to do something to the input
    return _object2.func2(function1(input))
```

And for the user, they won't be able to access any of the `_object1` or `_object2` form the `topmost` and in the `topmost.__init__.py`, only the functions from `submodule` were imported:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from topmost.submodule import *
```

And when the users use the `topmost` library, they will only be expose to:

```
>>> import topmost
>>> topmost.function1('foo bar')
>>> topmost.function2('foo bar bar')
>>> topmost.function1('blah blah black sheep')
```

When the first instance of `topmost.function1('foo bar')` is called, the interpreter should kick-in the global `_object1` within the `topmost.submodule` scope. **But would the `_object1` be destructed after the `topmost.function1` receives the returned value?**

**More importantly**, when the second instance of `topmost.function1('blah blah black sheep')` is called in the usage snippet above, would the `_object1 = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl', 'rb'))` be reloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Global variables linger.  They do not get destructed by a garbage collection.  The module `submodule` will keep its set global variables until such a module-global variable gets unset explicitly using `del` or if the module gets unloaded itself which normally doesn't happen.

Your usage of global variables in this fashion looks a bit fishy to me, though.  It is not a very clean way of writing code.

Why not setting the variables in general upon importing them?  You could set them to `None` and check for them having this value instead of catching `NameError`s.

Comment: Regarding the "variable checking" and global variable usage, I also think that there should be a better to resolve this. I've asked a separated question on that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907083/creating-a-decorator-cache-for-checking-global-variable

Answer (score 0):

As Alfe alludes to, you are using global vars in a weird way.

If you must use global variables, I would recommend that you rewrite the code:

```
import pickle
_model1 = None  # here we define the global we wish to load the 
                # first time either function is called

def load_model1():
    global _model1
    if not _model1:
        _model1 = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl', 'rb'))
        # No need to write two functions for loading model1
    return _model1

def function1(input):
    return load_model1().func1(input)

def function2(input):
    # Use function1 to do something to the input
    return load_model1().func2(function1(input))
```